# Setting position limits when moving a UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In one of my viewcontrollers, I have two views that move when a pan or swipe gesture is detected.  When these views begin moving, I've set a limit to how far they can move.  I have them working, but I was wondering if there is a proper way of setting these limits.

For instance, when my pan gesture method is called the following occurs:

```
if(sineCenter.y>=(self.view.bounds.size.height -40) && sineCenter.y<= (self.view.bounds.size.height + 100))
    {
        self.sineWave.center = sineCenter;
    }
```

Is there a more consistent way of doing `self.view.bounds.size.height -40` and `self.view.bounds.size.height + 100`.  By consistent, I mean the code will adapt to whatever the size of the screen is.  I'm thinking about releasing my app for both iphone and ipad. Right now I'm just setting these limits by eyeballing where I want the limits to be.

Comment: You can do this by creating a smaller subview over the parent view, and handle touches on the subview, and by just validating `< frame.x + 10.0` `< frame.y + 10.0` `> frame.width - 10.0` `> frame.height - 10.0` giving 10.0 padding..

Comment: What do you mean by smaller?

Comment: smaller means a UIView subview of smaller frame than your parent View, or how much area you want to cover in parent for pan move.

Comment: I don't understand how that would make it more practical?